# How to set selected value on a databound dropdownlist from a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Ok, so i have a dropdownlist that is originally populated from the database. Now based on a datatable, i want the selected value to be equal to the text residing in the database.  Whatever i do, it only shows "---Select One---" which is the only item i added manually to the dropdownlist items list to show a default value if the value i'm pulling is null (or that's what i want to do)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Master.TopLabel = "Survey Creation";
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            SqlConnection Connection = DatabaseConnection.GetSurveySystemConnection();

            string sqlquery = "SELECT S.[Survey_Desc], S.[Start_Date], C.[Category_Name] ,S.[End_Date], S.[Audience] FROM [Survey] S  Inner Join Category C On S.Category_ID = C.ID Where S.[ID] =" + Session["Survey_ID"];

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, Connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(DT);

            if (DT != null)
            {
                DescriptionMemo.Text = DT.Rows[0]["Survey_Desc"].ToString();
                CategoryDropDownList.SelectedIndex = CategoryDropDownList.Items.IndexOf(CategoryDropDownList.Items.FindByText(DT.Rows[0]["Category_Name"].ToString()));
                StartDateCalender.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(DT.Rows[0]["Start_Date"].ToString());
                EndDateCalender.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(DT.Rows[0]["End_Date"].ToString());
                string Audience = DT.Rows[0]["Audience"].ToString();
                if (Audience == "Students Only")
                {
                    AudienceRadioGroup.Items[0].Selected = true;
                }
                else if (Audience == "Staff Only")
                {
                    AudienceRadioGroup.Items[1].Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    AudienceRadioGroup.Items[2].Selected = true;
                }


            }
          Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

DropDownList in aspx page.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="CategoryDropDownList" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Category_Name" 
                    DataValueField="Category_Name" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="16px" 
                    Width="200px">
                    <asp:ListItem>---Select One---</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

The sql datasource select command.

```
SELECT [Category_Name] FROM [Category]
```

EDIT : This is full code, but i didnt know if it was relevant, sorry.

Comment: Can you provide us the full cade ? Are you sure that the databind of your dropdownlist is made before your page_load ?

Comment: is always selecting  the first row intentional?

Comment: please post the code that populates the list

Comment: I select from the first row because the session is saved after selecting a record in a gridview. and the dropdownlist is bound by a sqldatasource from the outside.

Comment: Maybe you can try to do it in the pre_render function. You copy the code provide as an answer below but instead of copying it in the page_load you copy it in the pre_render

Comment: I don't know what you mean by pre_render :(

Comment: protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{...} [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: You can also use SelectedValue insteadof SelectedItem. CategoryDropDownList.SelectedValue = DT.Rows[0]["Category_Name"].ToString()

Comment: This worked :D  =>  CategoryDropDownList.SelectedValue = DT.Rows[0]["Category_Name"].ToString();

Answer (score 3):

Change :

```
CategoryDropDownList.SelectedIndex = CategoryDropDownList.Items.IndexOf(CategoryDropDownList.Items.FindByText(DT.Rows[0]["Category_Name"].ToString()));
```

to

```
CategoryDropDownList.SelectedValue = DT.Rows[0]["Category_Name"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. don't use a global connection in ASP.NET (at least, don't make them static)since it is a multi threading environment. Instead always close connections as soon as possible best by using the `using-statement`
2. put an `if(!IsPostback)` check into `Page_Load`, don't databind controls on postback when `EnableViewState` is set to `true`(default). Otherwise events won't be triggered and values(like `DropDownList-SelectedIndex`) are overridden.

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        string sqlquery = "SELECT S.[Survey_Desc], C.[Category_Name], FROM [Survey] S  Inner Join Category C On S.Category_ID = C.ID Where S.[ID] =" + Session["Survey_ID"];
        using(var con=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con))
        using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(DT);
            DescriptionMemo.Text = DT.Rows[0].Field<string>("Survey_Desc");
            string categoryName = DT.Rows[0].Field<string>("Category_Name");
            CategoryDropDownList.SelectedIndex = CategoryDropDownList.Items
                .IndexOf(CategoryDropDownList.Items.FindByText(categoryName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The survey_desc populates the memo no problem, but the category dropdownlist still doesnt do anything.

Comment: @BasharKH: Do you really need to use the `SqlDataSource` control?(i wouldn't use it in production but for demo pages) Instead bind it manually in the  `if(!IsPostBack)` code above just before the `CategoryDropDownList.SelectedIndex` part.

Comment: I just did this, and it worked CategoryDropDownList.SelectedValue = DT.Rows[0]["Category_Name"].ToString();

Comment: @BasharKH: Yes, if your `DataTextField` is the same as the `DataValueField`.

Answer (score 0):

OnPageLoad
    CategoryDropDownList.Items.FindByText(categoryName).selected = true;